# Is this following SDP problem Convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Is the following problem convex function?

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
\underset{\mathbf{X}} {\text{minimize}}\,\,\,\, & \text{Trace}(\mathbf{RX})
\\ \text{subject to} &\\
& \text{Trace}(\mathbf{Q_{k}X}) = {0}\,\, k = 1,2...N\\
&\mathbf{AX} = \mathbf{0} \\
& \text{Trace}(\mathbf{X}) = {1} \\
& X\succeq 0,\,\, X \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}.
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}
Where, $\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times M}$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix.

and

$\mathbf{Q_{k}} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}\,\, k = 1,2,...N$ are the symmetric Toeplitz matrices, like the matrices given below
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
Q_1 &= \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
     1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
     \end{array}
     \right]\\ 
     \end{aligned}
     \end{eqnarray}
             and 
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
Q_2 &=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
       \end{array}
       \right]
    \end{aligned}
    \end{eqnarray}
In General,
$ Q_k$ = Toep( [0 0 0... 1 ... 0\, 0] ), Where $1$ is at $k^{th}$ position.

and

$\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{V \times M}$, $V < \frac{M}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's convex.

Note that $trace(A X)$ is just a linear function.  So you're minimising a linear function subject to a bunch of linear equality constraints and a positive semidefiniteness constraint.